# How add Pie chart ShowEffect and HideEffect in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

Im trying to add showEffect and HideEffect for pie chart.Did not find good example.Guys do you have any idea about this ?

Comment: Check [this](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/09/24/animating-data-changes-in-a-flex-pie-chart/)

Comment: That example is a good one thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you work on the Chart PieSeries and play with interpolated and shadows, plus some effects of rotation.
The leave some links that may be useful

[Link 1](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/11/22/animating-a-flex-piechart-controls-rotation-when-a-user-clicks-on-an-item/)

[Link 2](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Flex/Chart/SeriesSlideeffectforPiechart.htm)

[Link 3](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/09/24/animating-data-changes-in-a-flex-pie-chart/)